# How to delete widgets from another page in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I have a delete button that deletes widgets from another page. However, the button doesn't actually delete the widget. The button also should delete the json object that is attached to the widget but it doesn't do this either.

code:

```
    # displays the streak that was clicked on in screen two
    def display_streak(self, obj):
        self.third_screen()
        name = obj.id
        bottle = self.root.get_screen("three")
        can = self.root.get_screen('two')
        bottle.ids.del_space.add_widget(Button(id=name, text="Delete", size=(60,25), size_hint=(None,None),
                                    font_size=18, on_press=self.del_button)) # fix later
```

```
def del_button(self, obj):
        bottle = self.root.get_screen("two")
        can = self.root.get_screen('three')
        name = obj.id

        with open("streak.json", "r+") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        for child in self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.children:
            if child.text == name:
                print("delete")
                bottle.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.remove_widget(child)

                for i in xrange(len(data)):
                    if data[i] == name:
                        data.pop(i)
                        break

                open("streak.json", "w").write(json.dump(data, sort_keys=True, indent=4))
```

I was trying to compare the id of the Button in `del_space` to the text inside of the widgets in `streak_zone` inorder to delete but for some reason this isn't working. I even passed obj from `on_press=self.del_button` and it still does not work, how come?

***EDIT***

`obj` in `display_streak()` is passed from a conditional that binds the function to a button widget:

```
elif delay > time.time() > self.honey:  # on time (green)
                    child.background_normal = ''
                    child.background_color = [0, 1, 0, .95]
                    child.unbind(on_press=self.early_click)
                    child.bind(on_press=self.add_score)
                    child.bind(on_press=self.display_streak)
                    child.bind(on_press=self.draw_streak)
```

***EDIT***

I'm not sure but I believe that the problem may be coming from my kivy code:

```
<ScreenTwo>
    id: screen_two
    name: "two"
    on_leave: app.restart()
    on_enter: app.display_btn()
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            ScrollView:
                BoxLayout:
                    id: streak_zone
                    orientation: 'vertical'
                    height: self.minimum_height
```

When entering page two `display_btn` is activated

Python:

```
def display_btn(self):
        ...

            for value in data.values():
                if value['delta'] is not None:
                    print(f"action={value['action']}, delta={value['delta']}, grace={value['delay']}")
                    streak_button = StreakButton(id=(value['action']), text=value['action'],
                                                 color=(0,0,0,1), size=(400, 50),
                                                 size_hint=(None, None))
                    self.root.screen_two.ids.streak_zone.add_widget(streak_button)
...
```

If this is the reason why the button won't be deleted, then how would I get around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the kv file deletes the widgets upon leaving, I need to just delete the json element with the same id as the widget

```
def del_button(self, object):
        name = object.id

        with open("streak.json", "r") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        with open("streak.json", "r+") as file:
            data = json.load(file)
            data.pop(name, None)
            file.seek(0)
            json.dump(data, file, indent=4)
            file.truncate()

        self.change_screen()
```